# UK family visit visa refused because I have more family in the UK than in my home country

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image]

[image]

I applied for a UK visit visa with my mother to visit my sisters and other family relatives and to attend a cousin's wedding. My application was refused as you can see in the refusal letter.

Can anyone please tell me what I should do now, and how I can make my application better next time?

I have provided almost all documents. I received money last month from my family in my bank account to distribute money to the poor, as it was the Ramadan holy month and almost all my family sent me money for distribution. I wrote in my letter that I received money from my family to give to the needy here in my country but the ECO said I have not provided any document. What document do I need to provide as my family members transfered money directly to my bank account?

(My closing bank statement was Pkr: 1,287,000 on 27-06-2018 and he wrote Pkr 1,117,354. I don't think they checked all documents correctly).

I received rent from the shops that are built next to my home and I usually get cash in hand. I also wrote this in my letter. I provided rent papers but the ECO said the documents do not demonstrate that I actually receive rent. What other documents do I need to provide to prove that I receive rent?

I have 5 sisters and other family members in the UK. That's why I want to go there and visit them. All of my sisters and their families have wanted to visit us in Pakistan but it is not easy for them as there are 24 of them in total, including their children. I wrote this in my letter and I also wrote that I will come back because I have property here and shops on rent, and I also have two sisters and the children here, but the ECO said I have more family in the UK than Pakistan, and that I would not come back. Please tell me how I can show more ties here. I provided property paper, rent papers for the shops. What else do I need to provide?

Comment: `Please tell me how can i show more ties here i provided property paper rent papers for shops what else i need to provide` Unfortunately you can't. One way you can provide documentation about the rental property was if your tenants paid via check and wrote *rent payment* or something of the sort on it. Overall however I don't think that will change anything. For now being single with strong family ties in the UK will always be a stumbling block, unless perhaps you got married and have kids.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. There are more issues than just the bank statements.

Comment: Despite the ties you mention in Pakistan, the fact that your mother planned to visit the U.K. with you and the extent of your family in the UK makes you a high risk applicant in the eyes of the ECO.

Comment: Well My father passed away suddenly in April 2017. This has had a major impact on our family here in Pakistan and in the UK. It has been difficult to overcome the loss and my sisters have suggested to come to the UK for 6 weeks to have a break and spend time with family

Comment: @TheZealot Regular deposits consistent with the amount specified in the rental contract should be fairly convincing.

Comment: When you say "have two sisters and the children here" do you mean your children? How old are they?

Comment: I don't have children i am single i have two sisters and their children here in Pakistan

Comment: Well i will sort out the bank statement issue and rental issue but i am not sure what to do with the ties issue. Anybody any helpful information please.